# Why when adding two scores together, which go up in 0.5 steps, does the total box only produce integers without the half marks?

Tags: numbers, integer, decimal, addition

Two scores go up in 0.5 steps yet the total box only produces integers when one of the scores my be e.g. 3.5? Any reason and can it be corrected?

```
<body>
<form action="trial.php" method="post" name="trial" target="_top">
<label>Score1<input id = "scorebox1" type="number" value="0" max="20" min="0" step="0.5" size="5" 
maxlength="5" oninput="totalscore()"/></label>
<label>Score 2<input id = "scorebox2" type="number" value="0" max="20" min="0" step="0.5" size="5" 
maxlength="5" oninput="totalscore()"/></label>
<label>Total<input id = "totals" type="number" value="0" step="0.5" size="5" maxlength="5" 
oninput="totalscore()" disabled="disabled"/></label>

</form>

<script>
function totalscore(){  

var totals =
parseInt(document.getElementById('scorebox1').value) +
parseInt(document.getElementById('scorebox2').value);

document.getElementById('totals').value = totals;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the parseInt may only deal with Integers. By doubling up the values before and then halving them before displaying in the Total box gives the correct output. So this amendment to the Javascript gives what is wanted.

```
<script>
 function totalscore(){ 

 var    totals =
 parseInt(document.getElementById('scorebox1').value*2) +
 parseInt(document.getElementById('scorebox2').value*2);

 document.getElementById('totals').value = totals/2;
 }
 </script>
```

I suppose if dealing with money you could multiply by 100 and then divided by 100 to get it to work.